# Uwsgi, MySQL restart on reboot in a wrong order

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, uwsgi

I am trying to setup a django website on EC2, basically I want to start MySQL server, and Uwsgi after reboot.

In order to make MySQL start on reboot, I did:

```
sudo cp /opt/mysql/server-5.6/support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/
sudo update-rc.d mysql.server defaults
```

In order to make Uwsgi start on reboot, I created a file /etc/init/uwsgi.conf:

```
description "ubuntu uwsgi instance"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
exec uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/uwsgi.ini
```

However the problem is that I will need mysql to start first, right now it looks like Uwsgi starts first, and tried to connect to mysql, which fails, and mysql never gets started.

Could anyone help me on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When your computer starts up, it doesn't run the init.d scripts directly. Instead, depending on what's called the "runlevel", it runs the scripts in /etc/rcN.d (where N is the runlevel). You can determine the current runlevel with the runlevel command; mine returns 2 in normal operation. That means that when the computer started up, it ran the scripts in /etc/rc2.d. The contents of rc2.d are just symlinks to scripts in /etc/init.d, named according to whether they should be started or stopped, and the order they should be run.

Use the runlevel command to find out what runlevel your computer is at (probably 2), then look in /etc/rc2.d for a link named smthing like uwsgi, which will be a symlink to /etc/init.d/uwsgi, and rename it to zzz999 - or whatever it takes to get it to sort after the other entries - that will cause it to run last.

There's more information about init.d scripts and runlevels at https://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts

Comment: You solution works very well, thanks a lot, just one more question, what if I want to keep my "uwsgi.conf" file in /etc/init directory rather than have a script in /etc/init.d, I am wondering /etc/init and /etc/init.d which one will run first?

Comment: init files are supposed to run first, but you should try

Answer (score 0):

Even if you start MySQL before uWSGI you're not assured it will be available when uWSGI is managing requests.
At start MySQL does some checks on database, loads InnoDB indexes, recover from transaction log or it may even hang.

You shouldn't rely on that approach.

Instead add application logic that ensures you correctly handle unavailability of database, i.e. retrying or showing an error page to the user asking to retry.